# Under which version of ECMAScript, the React code will fall into?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

1. I know that React is an Advanced `Javascript` and so can I know into which `ECMAScript` version the React Library falls under?
    For example, the below React code comes from React Library which is built using JavaScript and I want to know under which version of `ECMAScript` the below React code falls under?

`ReactDOM.render(element, container[, callback])`

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use features from ES5, ES6, ES7, ES8 in react but it hard find libraries in ES5 that supports reacts. SO the ES6 + is most recommended.

Answer (score 0):

React Library falls under ES6, but you can use earlier versions of ECMAScript as well, you can refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html) if you are familiar with ES5.